# Embedding video using Craft 3 'Video Embedder' plugin

Tags: plugins, embed

In the example from the documentation on Craft 3 '**Video Embedder**' plugin:

```
{% set embed = craft.videoEmbedder.getEmbedUrl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xWpo5Dn254') %}

{% if embed | length %}
    <iframe src="{{ embed }}"></iframe>
{% endif %}
```

Can someone please give me full (i.e. total beginner!) instructions on how to get the URL to load.

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out - just needed to use the right syntax, for example:

```
{% set embed = craft.videoEmbedder.getEmbedUrl(entry.videoEmbed) %}

{% if embed | length %}
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive--mb-l embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe src="{{ embed }}" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it has causes a big PHP error if 'empty'...If you don’t have any content (i.e. it’s an optional field for someone to add a video embed to the page and the user chooses not to embed a video) it triggers a big PHP error:

```
Embed\Exceptions\InvalidUrlException

<url> malformed
```